# How To Sort Excel Pivot table chronologically

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I need help sorting my pivot table by months over a couple years. I've tried using a hyphen on the date column, a space.

[image]

My date column looks like this:

[image]

Could it be because yearMo is a calculated field?

I am using this formula: =CONCAT(L2,CONCAT(" ",M2))

The column datatype is 'date' .
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that excel recognizes your date, instead of the concat you could use

```
=date(M2,L2,1)
```

then custom format as `M YYYY` so you get the same result visually

The graph can thereby recognize it has a date to sort chronologically